# cannot connect iOS device to vmWare

Tags: iphone, usb, macos-sierra, vmware-player

I have searched a lot for this and tried many answers, but device is not connecting tho the vmware [image: added all the settings]

[image: but still showing the error]

all suggestions will be appreciated